# Hover not working correctly on dynamic buttons in Tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, ttk

I am dynamically generating buttons in a tkinter GUI. I want those buttons to change their image upon hover. If I try to do it without passing the button as a parameter, I get an error 'AttributeError: 'Event' object has no attribute 'config'. If I try to pass 'link_file' as a parameter to 'link_button_hover' & 'link_button_mouseoff', when the button gets added it immediately runs hover and mouseoff functions then sits on the mouseoff image.

```py
def link_button_hover(e):
    e.config(image=vid_link_hover_icon)

def link_button_mouseoff(e):
    e.config(image=vid_unlinked_icon)

def create_button()
    link_file = ttk.Button(new_spot_frame, text="...")
    link_file.grid(row=1,column=0)
    link_file.config(command=lambda button=link_file: open_file_dialog(button),image=vid_unlinked_icon)
    link_file.bind('<Enter>', link_button_hover)
    link_file.bind('<Leave>', link_button_mouseoff)
```

or if I try the version where I pass buttons as parameter:

```py
link_file.bind('<Enter>', link_button_hover(link_file))
link_file.bind('<Leave>', link_button_mouseoff(link_file))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Event` is an object with a number of attributes describing the event, but you are trying to `configure` it which is why you get the error. What you need is to use `event.widget` to properly retrieve the widget object:

```
def link_button_hover(e):
    e.widget.config(image=vid_link_hover_icon)

def link_button_mouseoff(e):
    e.widget.config(image=vid_unlinked_icon)
```

Or if you prefer to pass the widget as an arg in your binding, use `lambda`:

```
link_file.bind('<Enter>', lambda e: link_button_hover(link_file))
link_file.bind('<Leave>', lambda e: link_button_mouseoff(link_file))
```